# How to calculate the percentage of a column greater than average of column B In Excel?

Tags: excel, average, percentage, countif

I have column A as "OS" and column B as "Password not changed", sample data is as below,

[image]

I want to calculate the % of different operating systems whose password is greater than average(password not changed days), e. g `33.3 % Linux systems password > 1266`, where `1266` is the average of all the passwords for Linux systems i.e `AVERAGE(B3,B9,B10)`

How can I achieve this in one formula? 
I tried different formule like `=COUNTIF(A2:A18,"> "&AVERAGE(B2:B18))`, but I am not getting expected result and not understanding what should be used?
I don't know much of advance excel, can someone please help/guide?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand the question, kindly check if this is what you required -

[image]

The formula is - `=CONCATENATE(ROUND(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11, "*Linux*", $B$2:$B$11, ">"&AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$11, "*Linux*", $B$2:$B$11))*100/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11, "*Linux*"), 1), "% Linux systems password > ", ROUND(AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$11, "*Linux*", $B$2:$B$11), 1))`

Change all `Linux` to `Windows` as per your requirement.

Comment: thanks, but I want the percentage of "Linux"  whose corresponding "password not changed" value is greater than the average value, so in this case the average value is `"1085"` and there are 2 Linux rows matching the criteria `(A4 and A10)`,  so the percentage should be `2/3*100= 66.6%`

Comment: Oh now I got your question. But if the average value is `1085`, then only `A11` is matching your criteria which is greater than `1085`... But you are saying that `378` & `879` is matching the criteria. Can you explain?

Comment: Sorry my bad, you are correct, only A11 is matching, I rectify my comment, so there is only one Linux server fulfilling the criteria i.e `2000>1085`

Comment: How can I get just the %, so that I can use that else where? Using COUNTIF?

Comment: This is what i had tried, `=((COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$345,"*Windows*",Sheet1!$H$2:$H$345,">"&AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!H2:H345,Sheet1!E2:E345,"*Windows*")))/(COUNTIF(E2:E345,"*Windows*")))`